# Is Loop Invariant Proof a form of Induction?

Tags: proof-techniques, correctness-proof, induction, loop-invariants

As far as I see, what computer scientists refer to as loop invariant proofs are exact replicas of induction proof. Is it true? Can I state that loop invariant proof implies an induction? Is there a theoretical difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question. I think yes, a loop invariant proof implies induction. However, it also deals with the termination step which is outside of the scope of induction. So a loop invariant contains an induction proof, but goes beyond that, and so an induction proof does not do all that a loop invariant proof does.

> [(1)](http://www.columbia.edu/~cs2035/courses/csor4231.F05/heap-invariant.pdf) Here, showing that the invariant holds before the first iteration is like the
>   base case, and showing that the invariant holds from iteration to iteration
>   is like the inductive step.

---

[image]

---

[image]

---